# How to get source of view controller call?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 scenes that use that use the same view controller, because they're identical tabs in a tab-view app.

Anyways, how can I tell which one is calling the view controller, so I can choose what data to be shown in the table view?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, that is not good coding practice.  I highly recommend you have a separate ViewController for each scene.  However, if you insist on having two identically named bar items and further insist on one ViewController, you can assign each one a separate tag in the attributes inspector.  You can tell which bar item, and hence which tab, was selected with:

let barTag =  self.tabBarItem.tag

Comment: But maintaining 2 sets of 99% similar code is better practice?

Comment: Sure, you can take a shortcut. Any ways the tag ID method I gave you should work well.  Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank-you. I also found setting a title for the scene and accessing `self.title` worked well too.

Comment: There you go! Multiple ways.